# The probability that at least one of five cards features a horse

Tags: probability

From a package of cards featuring 15 with dogs, 16 with cats, 7 with mice, and 4 with horses, 5 cards are randomly selected. Find the probability that at least one of the five cards features a horse.

#### Progress

I tried $P(\text{No horse cards})= 1- P(\text{at least one horse})=1- (38/42) = 4/42$   but my teacher said it is wrong.

Comment: We need help knowing what you've already tried!

Comment: **Hint**: What is the probability that *none* of the cards features a horse?

1 - Pr(no horses) = Pr(at least one horse)

Comment: JMoravitx, i did that equation and got 4/42, but my teacher said it is wrong

Comment: Here is what I did...P(No horse cards)= 1- (38/42) = 4/42

Comment: @Kyla use an @ symbol to ping the person as you write a reply in comments so we get a notification.  The probabability that you did not get a horse for the *first* card is $\frac{15+16+7}{15+16+7+4} = \frac{38}{42}$.  Given that the first card was not a horse, the probability that the second card is not a horse is $\frac{37}{41}$.  Given that the first two cards are not horses, the probability that the third card is not a horse is $\frac{36}{40}$ (we have one fewer non-horse card and one fewer card total in the deck each time).  Use multiplication principle to get probability no horses after 5

Answer (score 1):

> Progress
>
> I tried P(No horse cards)=1−P(at least one horse)=1−(38/42)=4/42 but my teacher said it is wrong.

You want: $\;\mathsf P(\text{at least one horse}) = 1- \mathsf P(\text{no horses})$

Now, for the total event space, count the ways to select any $5$ cards from all $42$.   For the favoured space, count the ways to select $5$ cards from the $38$ cards which *don't feature horses*.   From this you obtain the probability of drawing no cards with horses.

Can you complete?

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to Graham's answer, treat the drawings as five separate events.

*i.e.* "no horses drawn" is equivalent to "first card isn't a horse" AND "second isn't a horse" AND ... AND "fifth isn't a horse".

Don't forget, though, when you consider each event the pack is one card smaller than before!